# Scan barcode from web apps via smartphone camera

Tags: java, mobile, web-applications, zxing, barcode-scanner

I got two methods to scan barcode via smartphone camera. First I'm using

```
<input id="demoFile" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

after searched some website, I found zxing web based web cam barcode decoder, and I found it using video, so I'm using the second method

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
</div>
<script>
 var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

</script>
</body>
```

it did work to access front camera from my phone. 
The problems are
1. how to take that video property from html as an object in java? 
This is the code for decoding barcode from image

```
InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.jpg");  
BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);  

LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);  
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));  
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();  
Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

I don't know how to change this part

```
InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.jpg");  
BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);
```

into my video object?

1. How to change video settings so it'll use rear camera instead of front?

note : I'm new in java and currently doing with Struts2 framework. Any help will be appreciate.